# Storm Trident Topology missing tuples while placing them in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, jms, hdfs, apache-storm, trident

I am running a storm trident topology with two two different spouts in two different streams. My spouts are JMS spouts and using HDFS State to persist tuples.

It is working fine if i just run one spout, I am getting all the records posted to the JMS queue in HDFS.

While running topology with two spouts connecting to two different queues I am getting less records compared to what i posted in the QUEUE. Am i doing some thing wrong here. Please let me know if there is any issue in the way i am doing this.

```
    TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();       
    topology.newStream("QueueSpout", TridentSpout).partitionPersist(tradeStateFactory,hdfsFields, new HdfsUpdater());       

    Stream TopicStream = topology.newStream("TopicSpout", TridentTopicSpout);
    TopicStream.each(hdfsFields, new CashFilter()).partitionPersist(cashStateFactory, hdfsFields, new HdfsUpdater());
    TopicStream.each(hdfsFields, new JournalFilter()).partitionPersist(journalStateFactory, hdfsFields, new HdfsUpdater());
    TopicStream.each(hdfsFields, new RcvdlvrFilter()).partitionPersist(rcvdlvrStateFactory, hdfsFields, new HdfsUpdater());
```

Answer (score 0):

The below configuration is working fine with topology.

This is happening because i did not use partition grouping.

It is working fine after using  Global and batch Global.

**shuffle**: Use random round robin algorithm to evenly redistribute tuples across all target partitions

**broadcast**: Every tuple is replicated to all target partitions. This can useful during DRPC – for example, if you need to do a stateQuery on every partition of data.

**partitionBy**: partitionBy takes in a set of fields and does semantic partitioning based on that set of fields. The fields are hashed and modded by the number of target partitions to select the target partition. partitionBy guarantees that the same set of fields always goes to the same target partition.

**global**: All tuples are sent to the same partition. The same partition is chosen for all batches in the stream.

**batchGlobal**: All tuples in the batch are sent to the same partition. Different batches in the stream may go to different partitions.

**partition**: This method takes in a custom partitioning function that implements backtype.storm.grouping.CustomStreamGrouping

The below topology config is working fine as desired.

```
    TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();       
    topology.newStream("QueueSpout", TridentSpout).batchGlobal().partitionPersist(tradeStateFactory,hdfsFields, new HdfsUpdater());     

    Stream TopicStream = topology.newStream("TopicSpout",   TridentTopicSpout).global();
    TopicStream.each(hdfsFields, new CashFilter()).partitionPersist(cashStateFactory, hdfsFields, new HdfsUpdater());
    TopicStream.each(hdfsFields, new JournalFilter()).partitionPersist(journalStateFactory, hdfsFields, new HdfsUpdater());
    TopicStream.each(hdfsFields, new RcvdlvrFilter()).partitionPersist(rcvdlvrStateFactory, hdfsFields, new HdfsUpdater());
```